# Furniture part identification

Tags: woodworking, furniture, wooden-furniture

Can anyone identify this furniture part? It's used in my Danish Modern style cabinet to hold the upper cabinet in place.

The middle brass part has female threads on both sides. The ends are screws.

I'm trying to find a source for them since my movers lost them, but without knowing the name it's hard to look call
 local furniture part stores to know if they have them.

[image: mysterynpart]

[image: mystery part]

Comment: Furniture screw connecting bolts.  Should be available from your local homer improvement.

Answer (score 2):

The furniture screw connecting bolts appears to be a correct answer but posted in the form of a comment. A quick search for the term results in many ambiguous results, but there are some specific solutions as well. Search for cap nuts for connector bolts:

http://www.rockler.com/cap-nuts-for-connector-bolts

[image: cap nuts for connector bolts]

You'll find the same site also carries the bolts in various finishes and lengths:

http://www.rockler.com/connector-bolts-statuary-bronze-connector-bolts

[image: connector bolt]

Comment: Yes it was a generic comment as I could not find an exact model or part number without correct length and finish.

Answer (score 1):

Other poster is correct; sometimes these are called sex bolts. No, I did not make that up, though I enjoyed typing it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Rockler also calls them "panel connectors." The size and width (5mm x 1.5") would be perfect except that they are in nickel/zinc and I want them in antique bronze to match the existing ones...

[image]

whereas Grainger calls them "[binding posts](https://www.grainger.com/product/GRAINGER-APPROVED-Binding-Post-WP73996/_/N-1z0dryp?s_pp=false&picUrl=//static.grainger.com/rp/s/is/image/Grainger/5MA53_AS01?$smthumb$#nav=%2Fproduct%2FGRAINGER-APPROVED-Binding-Post-WP73996%2F_%2FN-8jrZ1z0drypZ1z0nm01%3FR%3D5MA83%26_%3D1473044386948%26picUrl%3D%252F%252Fstatic.grainger.com%252Frp%252Fs%252Fis%252Fimage%252FGrainger%252F5MA53_AS01%253F%2524smthumb%2524%26s_pp%3Dfalse)" (and has them in dull brass):

[image]